# How to install Docker / ERPNext on Apple M1?

Tags: docker-compose, apple-m1, erpnext, frappe

I have been trying to install ERPNext in Docker on my M1 MacBook Pro using this example: https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/blob/main/docs/single-server-example.md

I struggled when deploying ERPNext getting this error:

> `no matching manifest for linux/arm64 in the manifest list entries`

I fixed it by adding `platform: linux/arm64` to my compose files.

Now everything seems to be up and running but I cannot for the life of me get to ERPNext. When I go to localhost on my browser nothing loads.

I also get this error when I run the image:

> `WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested`

I am not sure what to do now. Should I go in my compose files and change `platform: linux/arm64` to `platform: linux/arm64/v8`? Also, why would it say that the requested image's platform is linux/amd64 when I specified `platform: linux/arm64`?

If anyone has a working tutorial on how to install the containerized version of ERPNext on M1 please share it with me :) .

Thank you!

Comment: Successfully built and run ERPNext on M1 (MacBook 14). 
1. `git clone https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker`
2. Add `platform: linux/amd64` to all services in the /pwd.yaml. 
3. Run `docker-compose -f ./pwd.yaml up`. 
4. Wait couple of minutes. 
5. Open localhost:8080

Answer (score 1):

Successfully built and run ERPNext on Apple Macbook (Apple Silicon).

1. Git clone https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker
2. Add platform: linux/amd64 to all services in the /pwd.yaml.
3. Run `docker-compose -f ./pwd.yml up`
4. Wait couple of minutes.
5. Open localhost:8080

– @victor fortin, Feb 2 at 17:57

Comment: should this be arm64 or amd64?